# .Net MVC4 redirect to action not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is probably a silly question, but it seems as though RedirectToAction() isnt working correctly.

I have an Admin Controller done as a separate area, and I have a logout task method, and I am simply trying to get the method to redirect to the website index on logout, but it is taking me to a url under the admin route instead and I have no idea why as I am calling the method giving it the controller name and action method name inside that controller.
instead it takes me to:
http://localhost:63374/Admin/Home

Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
        [Route("logout")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
    {
        var authManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

        authManager.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When not specified, the route values are persisted between calls.  Since you are in the admin area and not specifying an area in your `RedirectToAction` method, the route engine is keeping the reference to the admin area.

To solve this, you can either:

- Move your logout action outside of the admin area or,
- Specify that the `RedirectToAction` should find a controller outside of the current area by setting the area to an empty string.

`return RedirectToAction("Index", new{controller="Home", area=string.Empty});`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`. As i know, all these `Redirect*` and `RedirectTo*` methods are case sensitive

Comment: No that sadly doesnt work, it still takes me to Admin/Home

Comment: Maybe thats because `Admin/Home` is your default route? And when you signed out it redirects to it because you have not access to `Home/Index`? Did you use `AuthorizeAttribute` on `Home` controller or `Index` method of `Home` controller

Comment: These methods are **NOT** case sensitive by default.  I think there maybe some config settings around that, but not out of the box just fyi.  PS, not shouting, just wanting a focal point on the not part. :)